# Programs run fine with LibGDX -desktop but not LibGDX - Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

So I have just set up Eclipse to work with LibGDX using Gradle. After I installed I noticed there was a problem with the Android package, there was a red cross next to the package. When I opened it further there was a red cross next to src then com.myname.game.android and then in AndroidLauncher.java. When I opened the AndroidLauncher.java, this was the code I got:

```
package com.faturbansloth.game.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.faturbansloth.game.MyGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new     AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGame(), config);
    }
}
```

When I looked at the errors in he code of AndroidLauncher.java they were saying:

```
-The type android.os.Handler cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
required .class files 
-The import android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved
-Multiple markers at this line
- The type android.app.Activity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
- The hierarchy of the type AndroidLauncher is inconsistent
-Bundle cannot be resolved to a type
```

I am using SDK Manager 22.6.2 with the newest Gradle plugin for Eclipse. I have JRE 8 and JDK 7. Is there anyway to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435315/android-os-bundle-cannot-be-resolved-in-libgdx-android-project?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice this when I searched.

Answer (score 5):

There was no Android Version selected by default, so go:
`Project -> Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target` and select your preferred version

Comment: great: it worked (now I notice the error in the log: `Unable to resolve target 'android-19'` which would have been a hint to this)

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why this works but it does for me. I installed the ADT plugin, refreshed the android section and the red cross disappeared.

Refer to the section under "Download the ADT Plugin" to install the ADT plugin.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

After that, go to Eclipse > Package Explorer > Left click on Project-android > Select Refresh.