# Many compiling errors keeping me from exporting with no answer so far

Tags: java, android, eclipse

**My** -

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements
        ActionResolver, GameHelperListener {"
```

**says**-

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type android.app.Activity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
     referenced from required .class files
    - The hierarchy of the type AndroidLauncher is inconsistent
```

**My beginning package says** -

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type android.content.Intent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
     referenced from required .class files
    - The type android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
     referenced from required .class files
```

All of these errors are inside my androidlauncher.java. I am using Eclipse. I just fixed all of my compilation errors other than in my games android folder.I have tried everything so far, and cannot find a solution. Keep in mind I am very new to this. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is `AndroidApplication`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programs run fine with LibGDX -desktop but not LibGDX - Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094436/programs-run-fine-with-libgdx-desktop-but-not-libgdx-android)

Comment: Ok so i just followed these directions and now nothing can be resolved after going to project build target and checking android 6.0. I can't uncheck it now.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094436/programs-run-fine-with-libgdx-desktop-but-not-libgdx-android

Comment: The SDK needs to be set, so I'm not sure why you are wanting to uncheck it

Comment: It wasn't checked by default like his,and I checked it to receive more errors. Any idea? "Everything cannot be resolved" now. Some by "type or variable."

Comment: I can't really answer that without some more descriptive errors, sorry. Overall, it sounds like your build path is messed up. 1) Update the SDK 2) Set the SDK 3) Make sure you've included the necessary dependencies in your build path.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by exporting? Or are you trying to importing an android project? It looks like your build path settings are messed up. This happens sometimes with eclipse. You can try removing and re-adding the JRE to your project.

If that doesn't work, have you installed the ADT (android developer tools) plugin for eclipse? You need that to develop android apps in eclipse.

Alternatively, you could download and use Android studio and try opening the project there.

Comment: Ecporting as an Apk sorry. Regardless, I need to remove the errors. I have added the tools, removed, and added back the JRE. I might just do that . Thanks.