# Slowdown after solving import issue

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, libgdx, slowdown

I had hard time moving my project to new computer. Finally it started working well. But after some time I start getting error on android part:

```
the import android.os.bundle cannot be resolved
```

I found solution here: [android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved in libgdx Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435315/android-os-bundle-cannot-be-resolved-in-libgdx-android-project)

So, (as I commented there) I set another android version (from 4.0.3 to 4.4.2) then switched back. Basically I didn't do anything - it started working magically as it stopped.

Now both are working but with huge slowdown when starting or when switching screens. I'm getting those errors when I do that (go to another screen).

```
01-25 12:54:10.678: W/AudioTrack(8710): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
01-25 12:54:25.413: E/MediaPlayer(8710): Should have subtitle controller already set
01-25 12:54:25.413: E/MediaPlayer(8710): Should have subtitle controller already set
```

As you see it takes about 15 seconds to switch the screens and it use to take max 1 second. Any idea what is going on here? How can project suddenly start trowing new errors without modifications on my side?

Comment: because it does not create a new project with the setup of libgdx that same name as your project and copy all its contents, I am referring to, assset and code, just not take long to do and solve the problem is just an idea

Comment: Yes, that's my idea too - to save the code & assets and start from scratch. But I was hoping it's something trivial, that can be easier solved.